# How do I delete friends from my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

I have friends that are no longer active on my Facebook account.  How do I delete them and get them off my friends list?

Answer (score 2):

If you're removing many friends at the same time, it's likely more convenient to use your friends list:

Go to your profile then click on the "Friends" tab under your banner. Here you can see all of the friends that you have on Facebook. To remove a friend, hover over the "✓ Friends" button next to their name. In the drop down that appears, click "Unfriend" and they will no longer be a friend with you on Facebook.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think (but am not sure!) what you want is:

[image: WA107438 example]

From [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/172936839431357?helpref=faq_content).